# Geth synchronization shows no smart contracts

Tags: go-ethereum

I synchronized my ethereum node using the command

```
geth --syncmode "fast"
```

Now I wanted to access a smart contract, e.g. the one of OmiseGO. Unfortunately this is not found. I tried web3 and also a WebGUI etherparty/explorer. Both didn't find anything. No contract address at all. However it found the corresponding transaction, that created the smart contract.

For web3 I used the following code:

```
var code = web3.eth.getCode('0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07');
```

The code was always 0x which represents that the contract is not present.

Is it because of the syncmode fast that these kind of things are not stored?

Comment: Does your node finished syncing? What does `eth.blockNumber` return? What version of geth are you using?

Comment: ok, looks like I've been to impatient. It was nearly finished syncing, and the blocks where the smart contract was created were synced long ago. So I assumed everything created in this blocks should be there. Thank you for your clarification! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

If you run geth in syncmode fast, it means it only downloads the transactions, but is not processing them. Therefore, everything, that was created by these transactions will not be available. If you want to have the smart contracts, you have to do a full sync.

```
geth --syncmode "full"
```

and to speed up I recommend to increase the cache. I'm running it with

```
geth --syncmode "fast" --cache=2048
```

I have 16GB of RAM

Comment: Fast mode will download the current state (balances and contracts code), only after it has finished syncing. The difference between full and fast is how processing of blocks is done, old version of geth will store all intermediate states, but from v1.8 they will be discarded and only keep the more recent ones.